# Updating a data in Oracle dB

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

I have a datas in my Oracle DB that look like these :
2015-2265-0201 (dddd-dddd-dddd) in a column called "cote".

However, through a bad manipulation, some of these look like these :
201522650201

or these:
2015-2265-02-01

I want to change them so i ran these command :

```
UPDATE CSL.STOCKAGES
    SET
        COTE = REGEXP_REPLACE(COTE, '(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)' , '\1-\2-\3')
    WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d');
```

```
UPDATE CSL.STOCKAGES
SET
    COTE = REGEXP_REPLACE(COTE, '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d)-(\d\d)' , '\1\2')
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d');
```

However it doesn't work.
I tried to see what the datas look like and when i run :

```
SELECT * FROM CSL.STOCKAGES WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d');
```

It shows my datas that are correct but when I run :

```
SELECT * FROM CSL.STOCKAGES WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM CSL.STOCKAGES WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d');
```

It doesn't show me anything. What am I doing wrong ? Why the datas don't show ?

Here you can see a sample of the datas  :
[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cZcM.png)

Comment: It looks like your data is a little different from what you think it is. Maybe some control character hidden in the strings somewhere? Or a unicode dash instead of a minus sign? Something along those lines. Try `SELECT cote, dump(cote) FROM csl.stockages WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d');` and see if you spot anything.

Comment: Clearly a good idea !
But it returns 0 rows retrieved. I don't know what to think about that

Comment: Oops, my mistake We must check the strings from start to end: `SELECT cote, dump(cote) FROM csl.stockages WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COTE, '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$');`.

Comment: Still the same result sadly

Comment: Then there just is no invalid data in the table. Maybe there is another table you are confusing it with?

Comment: Thank you ! Yes it was a problem with the connexion to the database !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine all of your regular expressions into a single statement:

```sql
UPDATE CSL.STOCKAGES
SET COTE = REGEXP_REPLACE(
             COTE,
             '(\d{4})-?(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})',
             '\1-\2-\3\4'
           )
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(
        COTE,
        '(\d{4})-?(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})'
      )
AND   NOT REGEXP_LIKE(
        COTE,
        '\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}'
      );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stockages (cote) AS
SELECT '200209650304' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '200209650301' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '200209650302' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-2265-02-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-2265-02-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-2265-0203' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-2265-0202' FROM DUAL;
```

After the update the table contains:

> | COTE |
> | --- |
> | 2002-0965-0304 |
> | 2002-0965-0301 |
> | 2002-0965-0302 |
> | 2015-2265-0204 |
> | 2015-2265-0204 |
> | 2015-2265-0203 |
> | 2015-2265-0202 |

---

If you are finding that it does not update some rows then you need to check the values of those rows and see if there are some values that do not match your regular expression:

```sql
SELECT COTE, DUMP(cote)
FROM   CSL.STOCKAGES
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(
         COTE,
         '(\d{4})-?(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})'
       );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7905c02d34fdabc34fd2e5afa2b43860)*

Comment: Thank you ! This is clearly simplier than what I did, I had a problem to connect to the database and that's also why I was strugling